# Chef: Jenkins supermarket cookbook automated job deployment

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, bitbucket

I am currently using the [Jenkins supermarket cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins) to deploy an instance of Jenkins running as a service on my Chef managed node. So far I have modified my _master_war_ recipe file to install Jenkins and start Jenkins as a service using runit, install all plugin versions I need as well as enable matrix based security and create a base administrator account. It should also be noted we are using BitBucket for source control.

I also want to add my jobs as part of the automated Jenkins deployment. From what I understand, the way to do this is to copy the job configuration files from a directory on my chef workstation to a directory (Chef's cache path), on the managed node.

Per the [Jenkins public supermarket cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins) readme:

> The :create action requires a Jenkins job config.xml. This config file
>   must exist on the target node and contain a valid Jenkins job
>   configuration file. Because the Jenkins CLI actually reads and
>   generates its own copy of this file, do NOT write this configuration
>   inside of the Jenkins job. We recommend putting them in Chef's file
>   cache path.

As these job configurations do change periodically, I'm wondering what is the best way to maintain the most recent copy of the job configuration file(s)  on my chef workstation for deployment to my managed node?

Am I understanding the cookbook documentation correctly in that we will need a local copy of the job configuration file (on the Chef workstation), that is then copied to Chef's cache file path on the managed node?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone is able to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I count setting up Jenkins jobs a lot more into the domain of Jenkins instead of Chef. The Jenkins community has developed several "jobs as code" approaches, the most popular ones being the [Job DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) and the [Jenkins Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), with the latter one being the probably better starting point.

What remains up to the Chef cookbook is to define the seed job, either e.g. for the "Bitbucket Organisation Folder" plugin (and the one job that points to your organisation at BitBucket) or a so-called "Seed job" for the Job DSL.

Regarding automated setup of pipelines, I recommend a look at [Torben Knerr's examples](https://github.com/tknerr/jenkins-pipes-jobs). This uses

- Pipeline (as defined in `Jenkinsfile`s) for the actual build jobs
- a Job DSL seed job to set up the pipeline job(s)

Regarding the actual implementation in Chef, you can see an example in [a cookbook of mine](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/site-chefcitypo3org/blob/7f8f7bf34c8b0eb48a4993f47430be0171f2fb7f/recipes/_jenkins_jobs.rb#L7-L21). The `template` resource copies a file from the cookbook (in the `templates/` subdirectory) into some temporary path, from where the `jenkins_job` resource picks it up (on the Jenkins server).

So I'm not sure, if you got it right regarding:

> will need a local copy of the job configuration file (on the Chef workstation)

So you just need it once on your workstation to add it to the cookbook, yes.

Comment: I've heeded your advice and began investigating Jenkins Pipeline's [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/) as a possible solution. Thank you for the advice @StephenKing.